# Get all events from a calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I made a calendar for my team and I would like to make a function that invites every member of a team to **every event** in that calendar. Is that even possible?

Is there a way how to call every event in specific calendar?

I tried to find a way on the web and found nothing helpful so far.
I thought I could use `getsEvent (starTime,endTime)` and set `endTime` to something like "infinity", but couldn't find if it's even possible.

Comment: I don't see why not. You should try it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific, meaning only one question per post. Please narrow the scope of your question, show what you have tried and be more specific about your search efforts for related questions from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén thanks a for your answer. I am not sure how do you mean "more specific" in this case? Could you direct me somehow? I used google and searched for variantions of "apps-script infinite end time" or "how to get all events from calendar apps script" etc. and found nothing useful on google or youtube or stackoverflow. But as I said, I am new to IT, I am more like a mannager of a small company, teaching myself how to improve our workflow to make less byrocracy

Comment: @Cooper and do you have any idea how to do it? I haven't figure it out :D

Comment: Have you looked at Calendar API?

Comment: Try the list method. Keep paging until you don't get a nextPageToken.  I get event all the way back to 2017.  With API explorer you don't even have to write any code.